# roll value within grouped regions in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

consider the `df`

```
idx = map('first {}'.format, range(2)) + map('last {}'.format, range(3))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, -1), idx, idx)
df
```

[image]

I want to group the dataframe into four quadrants based on the text in the row and column headers.  Meaning that the upper left quadrant consists of columns with `'first'` and rows with `'first'`.  The upper right quadrant consists of columns with `'last'` and rows with `'first'` and so on.

Then within each group, I want to

- roll each element one to right if it can
- otherwise start on next row at the beggining if it can
- otherwise start at the very beginning

This should help illustrate

[image]

The expected output should look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a nested groupby-apply pattern and [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).  Perform a `groupby` on the columns, followed by a `groupby` on the index to get the desired subgroups to roll.  Then use `np.roll` to perform the roll, wrapping the output in a DataFrame since `np.roll` only returns an array.

```
def roll_frame(df, shift):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df, shift), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

# Groupers for the index and the columns.
idx_groups = df.index.map(lambda x: x.split()[0])
col_groups = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split()[0])

# Nested groupby, then perform the roll..
df = df.groupby(col_groups, axis=1) \
       .apply(lambda grp: grp.groupby(idx_groups).apply(roll_frame, 1))
```

Kind of gross, but gets the job done.  The order in which you perform the nested `groupby` doesn't really matter.

The resulting output:

```
         first 0  first 1  last 0  last 1  last 2
first 0        6        0       9       2       3
first 1        1        5       4       7       8
last 0        21       10      24      12      13
last 1        11       15      14      17      18
last 2        16       20      19      22      23
```

Comment: very nice!  way faster than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
sdf = df.stack()
tups = sdf.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: tuple(pd.Series(x).str.split().str[0]))

sdf.groupby(tups).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.roll(x.values, 1), x.index)).unstack()
```

[image]